# Scala - Variable amount of function arguments as method parameters

Tags: scala, function, methods, variadic-functions

I am a newbie fascinated by Scala looking for a way of creating a method/function that takes a variable amount of functions as parameters.

Example with the `*` notation used in regular VarArgs

```
def someMethod(aNumber: Int, multipleFunctions: Int => Boolean*) = {
    var flag = true
    for (func <- multipleFunctions; if (!func(aNumber)) flag = false
    flag
}
```

I realize I could accept an array of functions, but if that works it just feels like there must be a way of doing it with var args.

Comment: `fns: Function1[Int, Boolean]*`

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can simply wrap `Int => Boolean` in parentheses and that would solve the problem.

Comment: @cchantep Well that was quick, thank you very much. I'm guessing you already know but this can be also written as Function[Int, Boolean], IntelliJ seems to prefer it that way.

Comment: @stefanobaghino You are correct, I should probably have thought of that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` token is evaluated with precedence over `=>`, so you can simply solve your problem by wrapping the `Int => Boolean` type in parentheses:

```
def someMethod(aNumber: Int, multipleFunctions: (Int => Boolean)*)
//                                              ^     here!    ^
```